# 3D container and viewer control for WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d

Recently I have been working on a small WPF project involving the visualization and manipulation of 3d objects. For 2d ojects, this can be easily achieved with  a Canvas warpped in a ViewBox or some nice 3rd party controls. But I can't find any free, ready-to-use solution for 3d objects. There is a likely one in WpfToolKit from XceedSoftware(https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit), but no information is given.

I know WPF has some 3D support, like ViewPort3D and other classes in Media3D namespace, and I did find a book, '3D Programming for Windows'(http://www.charlespetzold.com/3D/index.html), by Charles Petzold introducing the concept and basic knowledge. However, many tricky tasks like adjusting camera according to mouse and keyboard input is not presented. So before I start building my own control, I want to at least confirm that I'm not wasting my time doing something already perfectly done. And how to properly config the mouse and keyboard events to make the control behaves as if using some professional CAD softwares?

In short:
1.Any free 3d control for WPF
2.How to build my own ones

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Try  HelixToolkit

Comment: Yes, the HelixToolkit seems promising, and the first and latest build ver 1.0.0 came out mere two weeks ago. No wonder I didn't notice this one. That being said, this lib do suffer from a lack of documentation. I will look into it if no better choices available, thanks pal :)